# How to create scrollable dropDown list in html

Tags: html, css

I have drop down list:

```
<ul class="dropNav" ng-init="loadPage('countByDays', 'dataWithTrmGroup', selectedItem)" >
            <li>
                <img src="Images/toggle.png" />
                {{ selectedItem.name }}
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="group in groupsData | groupfilter:selectedItem.id"  ng-click="changeSelectedObject('countByDays', 'dataWithTrmGroup', group)">{{ group.name }}</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

and my css

```
.dropNav {
    cursor: pointer;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
.dropNav li {   
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    float: left;    
}
.dropNav li ul {
    display: none;  
}
.dropNav li {
    width:200px;
    display: block;
    background: #93297e;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: #fff;
    font-size:12px;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;   
}
```

when i am trying to put `overflow-y: scroll;`

it is scrollable but it is shown only 1 element of list . I want to see 10 element and others will be in scroll down.I have tried to set `<ul class="dropNav" size="10">` but no good result.

Comment: i think you should use angular select
<select ng-model="selectedName" ng-options="x for x in names">
</select>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you should use `angular-ui-select`. By using this you can easily use an image within a scrollable dropdown and also with text (if you want).

> [Working Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/lbzcem46F2UWUt4MIGJ3?p=preview)